# Resizing control flickering

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rendering, gdi+

So I have a resizable control which I'm using `WM_NCHITTEST` to resize. I have double buffered the control and I'm drawing a border. However, when resizing, I get medium flickering issues.
Here's the code for drawing:

```
if (_cachedPen == null)
{
    _cachedPen = new Pen(BorderColor, VisibleBorderWidth);
}
Rectangle clientRectangle = ClientRectangle;
if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Left) == BorderSides.Left)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(_cachedPen, clientRectangle.X, clientRectangle.Y, clientRectangle.X, clientRectangle.Height);
}
if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Right) == BorderSides.Right)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(_cachedPen, clientRectangle.Width - VisibleBorderWidth, clientRectangle.Y, clientRectangle.Width - VisibleBorderWidth, clientRectangle.Height);
}
if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Bottom) == BorderSides.Bottom)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(_cachedPen, clientRectangle.X, clientRectangle.Height - VisibleBorderWidth, clientRectangle.Width, clientRectangle.Height - VisibleBorderWidth);
}
if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Top) == BorderSides.Top)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(_cachedPen, clientRectangle.X, clientRectangle.Y, clientRectangle.Width, clientRectangle.Y);
}
```

And for resizing:

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:
{
    Point pos = PointToClient(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32()));
    if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Left) == BorderSides.Left && pos.X < PhysicalBorderWidth)
    {
        m.Result = new IntPtr(HTLEFT);
    }

    if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Bottom) == BorderSides.Bottom && pos.Y > Height - PhysicalBorderWidth)
    {
        m.Result = new IntPtr(HTBOTTOM);
    }

    if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Right) == BorderSides.Right && pos.X > Width - PhysicalBorderWidth)
    {
        m.Result = new IntPtr(HTRIGHT);
    }

    if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Top) == BorderSides.Top && pos.Y < PhysicalBorderWidth)
    {
        m.Result = new IntPtr(HTTOP);
    }
    return;
}
case 0x0014:
    return;
default:
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    break;
```

Note that `SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);` is on. However, when resizing, I get light-medium flickering. Is there any way to solve this?
Thanks

EDIT:
Also, just to note, it happens even when I don't cache the `Pen` objects.

EDIT:
Ok, so the painting is just called from `OnPaint`. The custom control just inherits from `Control`.
The definition of BorderSides is as follows:

```
[Flags]
internal enum BorderSides
{
    None = 0,
    Left = 1,
    Right = 2,
    Top = 4,
    Bottom = 8
}
```

And here are the constants:

```
private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
private const int HTBOTTOM = 15;
private const int HTLEFT = 10;
private const int HTRIGHT = 11;
private const int HTTOP = 12;
```

EDIT:
This is for a docking control. It doesn't have a graphic background, and I intend to inherit from it. It might host controls, but not right now. I'm testing all 4 border sides, and all have slight flickering issues.

Comment: Can you post the missing pieces (where the drawing methods are called, the definition of `BorderSides`, possibly the constants, so nobody need to go get them)? Plus, some more info on the functionality of this Control (is it a Custom Control, inheriting from `Control` or what else? Or is it a UserControl? Does it have a graphic background? Does it host other Controls? etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jimi! I updated the question.

Comment: *Plus, some more info on the functionality of this Control [...] Does it have a graphic background? Does it host other Controls?*. What is the `BorderSides` that you're testing (`(BorderSides & BorderSides.Left) == BorderSides.Left`)?

Comment: I updated my question.